# Branching in P4V, adding to an old CL but keeping the current one the main

Tags: perforce, perforce-branch-spec

Program has 2 versions, but it's currently one branch.

v1 i.e. Old GUI, stable, needs a small update
v2 New Gui, untested, is the current one

v1 has a bug that I want to fix, say I want v1.1, but then I want to go back to working on v2.

I need to do it using P4V (GUI version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want more than one branch for this.  I'd recommend creating a branch specifically for maintaining your v1 code.  Populate this branch from the last changelist that went into v1.  This way you keep your v2 code separate from your v1 code, and if you need to fix something in v1 and take that same fix in v2, you can integrate it back to your main branch.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/#chapter.codelines.html#d5e3626 has guidelines on branching strategies along with the instructions for creating and populating branches.